# How many threads can be created for completing the task?

Tags: python, multithreading

Here I am retrieving different webpages and then counting the frequency of alphabets and getting the final dictionary as an output. In this case I am going through 20 webpages `for i in range(1000,1020):`and therefore I ran a loop and created 20 threads. It is serving the purpose and is reducing a lot of time as compared to single thread. What if I wanted to retrieving 1000 of webpages, should I use loop to create different 1000 threads or is there any way to give some webpages as chunk to each thread ? Is there any limitation of creating the number of threads ?

```
import json
import json
import time
import urllib.request
from threading import Thread

finished_tasks = 0
def count_letters(url,frequency):
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    txt = str(response.read())

    for l in txt:
        letter = l.lower()
        if letter in frequency:
            frequency[letter] += 1
    global finished_tasks
    finished_tasks += 1

def main():
    frequency = {}
    for c in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz':
        frequency[c] = 0
    start_time = time.time()

    
    for i in range(1000,1020):
        
        p = Thread(target = count_letters,args =('https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc'+str(i)+'.txt',frequency))
        p.start()
    while finished_tasks < 20:
        time.sleep(0.5)
    
    end_time = time.time()
    print(end_time-start_time)
      
    print(frequency)

main()
```

Comment: There is both a hard limit set by the OS (after which your attempts to spawn new threads will fail) and a practical limit (where adding additional threads no longer speeds anything up and might slow things down).  Where those limits are depend on your OS, hardware, etc, but as a rule of thumb I’d recommend keeping your thread count in the dozens rather than the hundreds or thousands.

Comment: It makes sense to keep adding threads as long as there's a benefit to doing so, but at some point adding more threads doesn't allow for extra speed (since your computer is already using all the resources available: cpu, bandwidth, whatever restrictions of your OS' network stack, etc.) - at that point it makes more sense to write workers which will run on each thread, grabbing a new URL from a queue and processing it every time they are done, until the queue is empty.

Comment: Have you considered using a thread pool, which manages all that for you rather than doing it manually?

Comment: How can I allocate some tasks as a combo to each of the threads. I am only aware of giving one task to one thread by running a simply loop ?